# i can't assign one struct to another in c

Tags: c, struct

i have 2 structs, i want to assign one struct to another, but when i print the results, it prints crap, the functions : "ver_tope" is on charge to do that , what am i doing bad?, here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TAM 4

typedef struct{
        char nomyap[40];
        int edad;

}t_info;

typedef struct {
    t_info pila [TAM];
    int tope;

}t_pila;

void ver_tope(const t_pila *p, t_info *d);

int main()
{
    t_pila pila;
    t_info info;
    //I CHARGE BOTH STRUCTS

    ver_tope(&pila, &info);

    return 0;
}

void ver_tope(const t_pila *p, t_info *d)
{
   *d = p->pila[(p->tope)-1];
    return ;
}
```

Comment: You are using an uninitialized variable.

Comment: Can't reproduce with the code you provided. How about you help us help you, edit your post and include a [Minimal, Complete. Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: i have another function for that, but is so long so prefer to don't copy it(i already tested that function), do you see something strange in the code above ?

Comment: The line t_info pila [TAM]; will create an array with space for 4 t_info, but all of the memory is uninitialized.  You need to create t_info objects and put them in the array.

Comment: i will try thank you, i'm sorry for the poor clarity of my question

Comment: there is little info for solving your issue, such as what is the value of `tope`, is it guarantee to be `<TAM`

Comment: here is a minimal working exmaple of your code http://pastebin.com/JnUeFNHb

Comment: @dvhh: I think that's a little too minimal.  It would be better using the OPs structure types.

Comment: No, don't try stuff at random. Don't use `memcpy`. Work out what you did wrong. And then use assignment.

Comment: maybe it should be easier to point at a "how to use gdb" tutorial :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an initialisation for  pila.tope in main() ex:

```
...    //I CHARGE BOTH STRUCTS
pila.tope =2;
ver_tope(&pila, &info);
...
```

That stopped the  segmentation fault...

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    t_pila pila;
    t_info info;
    ver_tope(&pila, &info);
    return 0;
}
```

You have not initialized either variable. Since `pila` is the source of the assignment you can do the following:

```
int main()
{
    t_pila pila = { 0 };
    pila.tope = 1;
    t_info info;
    ver_tope(&pila, &info);
    return 0;
}
```

Here I default initialized `pila` and then set its `tope` member to `1`. I did not initialize `info` since `ver_tope` assigns to it. It would be clearer if you converted `ver_tope` into a function that returned `t_info`.